# Moving wiki pages

Tags: ros, wiki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to move multiple wiki pages under http://www.ros.org/wiki/swri-ros-pkg to http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial.  I cannot find an easy way to do this.  I could copy and past the content from the old pages to the new page, but it would required moving several attachment.  In this case, I would also have to delete the old pages, again something I am not sure how to do.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33571/moving-wiki-pages/) by [sedwards](https://answers.ros.org/users/78/sedwards/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1601 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does "`More Actions>Rename Page`" not work for you?

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2